# Fluent Nhibernate - ClassMaps in multiple, separate assemblies

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Consider the following **Fluent** configuration;

```
FluentConfiguration config = Fluently.Configure();
        config.Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbKey].ConnectionString));

        // MemberMap is in the same assembly as this class, contains
        // maps for member and role entities as part of a default
        // membership service provider
        MappingAssemblies.Add(typeof(MemberMap).Assembly);

        foreach (Assembly mappingAssembly in MappingAssemblies)
        {
            // For each assembly that has been added to MappingAssemblies
            // we add to the current mapping configuration.  This allows
            // me to drop this helper into any solution and it provide 
            // standardized membership abilities AS WELL AS manage
            // the solutions unique ClassMaps 
            config.Mappings(m => 
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly)
                );
        }

        if (exportSchema)
        {
            config.ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
                    {
                        new SchemaExport(cfg)
                        .Create(true, true);
                    }
                );
        }

        _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

This logic is held within a static class I call from within my Global.asax on application startup.  The startup configuration will look something similar to;

```
Database.MappingAssemblies.Add(typeof(PageContentMap).Assembly);
// This is the method detailed above
Database.FluentConfigureSessionFactory("MySolutionsDb", true);
```

So the idea is that I have packaged my Member and Role entity objects into the same assembly as the Database helper object so that any solution I care to create can instantly gain my standardized membership abilities as well as being able to simply create its own solution specific ClassMaps and add them to the configuration object.

The issue is, the familiar call to;

```
config.Mappings(m => 
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly)
                );
```

only seems to be able to deal with a single assembly. Doesn't matter what is added to the list, only the last assembly added will be mapped.  As an alternative to the above, I have tried holding a reference to `MappingConfiguration` (which is what 'm' stands for in the `config.Mappings(m => )` )  but this did not work either.  It is obvious that such a call to `m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly` or indeed any of the `FluentMappings.Add` methods will overwrite what is previously there but **surely** there is a way of getting this done ?  It doesn't seem like that much of a 'weird' requirement.

Comment: Just curious but why are you storing entities that are related to one database in different assemblies?  Not that this isn't a valid question but again just curious.

Comment: which version of FNH do you use? i remember there was a bug/limitation about multiple mapping-assemblies

Comment: @Cole W. So Member and Role entity objects come from the same assembly as the static Database class but still require the .AddAssemblyOf<Member>() call.  Then this is packaged into a .dll and referenced in a new solution i decide to make.  On top of this call to .AddAssemblyOf<Member>() in order to map the Member and Role objects to my new solutions database, i will also need to map the unique entity objects that are involved in this new solution; Which will not be in the same assembly in the aforementioned Member and Role objects.

Comment: @Firo - If i right-click on FlientNHibernate.dll and view "Product version", this reads: 1.3.0.717

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I managed to solve it after looking at this, so I'll try to answer it. This is how I did (the .ForEach() is an extension from NHibernate.Linq):

```
config.Mappings(m => MappingAssemblies.ForEach(a => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(a)))
```

I had to do it for auto-mapped stuff as well, and there the syntax is a bit different. I have an interface  that marks all classes I want to automap:

```
config.Mappings(m => 
    m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assemblies(MappingAssemblies.ToArray())
    .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IAutoMappedEntity)))))
```

Also, I don't have a "MappingAssemblies" that I set manually, I took the lazy approach of just including all my assemblies, so my config looks like this (using SQLite, this is from a test project):

```
var MappingAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("MyCompanyName."));
Configuration configuration;

var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory())
     // This adds fluent mappings
    .Mappings(m => MappingAssemblies.ForEach(a => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(a)))
     // This adds automapped classes using specific configuration
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assemblies(new MyAutomapConfiguration(), MappingAssemblies)))
     // This adds automapped classes that just use my magic interface
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assemblies(MappingAssemblies.ToArray()).Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IAutoMappedEntity)))))
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => configuration = cfg)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```